# Misuse of DNA leaks to create your clones, or children

Tags: dna, cloning

Recently, [sequenced DNA data leaks have been reported](https://www.theverge.com/2018/6/6/17435166/myheritage-dna-breach-genetic-privacy-bioethics).

The linked article discusses possible risks like blackmailing based on health related data.

However there could be one more misuse, at least theoretically, therefore this question. For not specialists, actually good to know.

Is it by current state of the art technically possible using this DNA data to (given you have fully sequenced DNA of an individuum):

- clone this individuum?
- engineer artificial gametes to breed his/her children?

Comment: I voted to close because this is science fiction, not present-day science, which should answer your question: We are not remotely close to being able to do what you suggest.

Comment: I don't understand, why this question gets down and close votes for basically asking "Is this science or fiction?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @iayork mentions in their comment, creating a human clone from a sequenced genome is still in the realm of science fiction. Also, DNA testing companies like MyHeritage don't sequence the client's entire genome. They typically analyze the client's DNA with a [SNP Chip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNP_array) that compares the client's DNA to known reference sequences at several thousand position with well known variations in the human population.